# XAMPP - MySQL doesn't have a port number - unable to connect

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am having issues with MySQL using XAMPP. When I start the MySQL service, it doesn't show a port number.

[image]

When I go to localhost/phpmyadmin, it is unable to connect.

[image]

I've even tried changing the port number in my.ini file but to no avail. The strange thing is that this was working a few minutes ago. I restarted the server, and boom it stopped working.

Any clue why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might have happened because you shut down your mysql service in the middle of an operation causing database page corruption, check the mysql_error.log and see if you have something like the following:

```
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 347144 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 734520
```

To fix this you need to start the service forcing InnoDB recovery, edit the my.ini file and place the following after the [mysqld] block:

(Make sure you have a backup of your database before doing this).

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

You might need an indes of 3 or 4 to make it work, check the [InnoDB Recovery Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) to see what you need.

After starting the mysql service you should be able to see the port again. Remember to remove the force recovery option after you've started your server again.

Answer (score 1):

Find `my.ini` file in your `mysql installation directory`, if it has been installed via `xampp` look into `xampp` directory for `mysql` folder.

See there what ports have been configured for now.

It should be 3306, but if not, change it to 3306 (as default).

You should also check your ports and their Listening Protocols.

To check ports on windows, Open CMD as administrator and type

`netstat -an`

and search for your port, it must be `LISTENING` and must be using `TCP` as protocol for communication. See below image for details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I once got a similar issue and the cause was that the port for MySQL was closed on that system. When I opened the port, it worked

Comment: But it has been working for me all this time. And I also tried changing the port numbers to 3307, 3308 and 3309.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using command line mysql -h <machine ip> -P <port> -u root -p password

Answer (score 0):

**netstat -tlpn**
It will show the list something like below:

*Active Internet connections (only servers)
**Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

PID/Program name**
tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
1393/sshd

Use as root for all details. The -t option limits the output to TCP connections, -l for listening ports, -p lists the program name and -n shows the numeric version of the port instead of a named version.

In this way you can see the process name and the port.If the port is closed the open the MYSQL Port.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally, it works when I run it with administrator right: click on xampp icon and click on run as administrator